# Error while installing project dependency in aurelia js

Tags: node.js, aurelia

Hello all I am new to aurelia js . I installed `aurelia js` through command line using `npm install aurelia-cli -g` command successfully.

After successful installation , I created one project using command `au new` , But when I am installing dependencies using command `npm install` I am getting error as below.

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0.1.10"},"devDependen'

.

Also I tried it after updating node version but nothing works. I am using below version of `node` and `npm` in windows

Node : 10.16.3

NPM : 6.9.0

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sometimes happens with CLI driven generators. Try the following:

`npm cache clean --force`

Then:

`npm i aurelia-cli -g`

You may need to reinitialise your Aurelia Application after doing this.

To further clarify, if the above doesn't work could you post a link to your package.json in a pastebin?

Comment: Thanks , It works for me . Please upvote the question

Comment: @Abhishek - Happy to help, and glad it worked. Those are often the most annoying types of problems!